# Knockout.js: Display observable attributes using the with binding.

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on moving a rails frontend to knockout.js. My MasterVM has a currentEvent- the event a user is working with, but I can't seem to access it's attributes in the view. I've tried following the single page application tutorial (to the point of c/p code) and  can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Within the developer console I can access EVM.currentEvent attributes so I know it's loading properly.

```
MasterVM.js

function MasterVM() {
   var self = this;    
   self.newItemName = ko.observable();
   self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.events = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.currentEvent = ko.observable();

   self.addEvent = function(data) { self.events.push(new Event(data));};

   self.removeEvent = function(event) { self.events.remove(event) }

   self.addItem = function() {
     self.items.push(new Item({ name: self.newItemName() }));
     self.newItemName("");
   };

   self.removeItem = function(item) { self.items.destroy(item);};

   self.getEvent = function(data) {
     $.ajax("/events/", {
        data: { id: 50 },
        type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) { 
            self.currentEvent = new Event(result) 
            console.log(currentEvent.name())
        }
    });
 }
 self.getEvent();
}
```

Here's how I am trying to access it in the view, I've tried many combinations and this one is lifted directly from the tutorial. The static html is not loading, there are no errors in the console.

```
edit.html.erb

<div class="editEvent" data-bind="with: currentEvent">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
        <p><span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
        <p><span data-bind="text: zip"></span></p>
        <p><span data-bind="text: date"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually **call** the observable, not to **replace** it:

```
self.getEvent = function(data) {
 $.ajax("/events/", {
    data: { id: 50 },
    type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(result) { 
        self.currentEvent(new Event(result));
        console.log(currentEvent.name())
    }
});
```

When you simply replace `currentEvent` (instead of setting its value), Knockout has no way to know that it changed and cannot update the view accordingly.